# Eclipse flickering on new line

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-16.04, eclipse-pdt

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Eclipse Neon. Everything looks OK but when I press enter, the new line flickering. Switching to the GTK2 solved the problem but I have some other issue in GTK2 such as scroll bar coloring and button coloring in the Dark theme.

Since I don't have any problem in GTK3 and the flickering is the only problem I have, how can I fix it in GTK3?

Here you can see how it flickers in GTK3

[image]

**EDIT**

Recently I tried Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.2 on Ubuntu GNOME, but the problem still exists. It Seems it's not the Unity problem.

Comment: You should open a bug ticket inside the Eclipse bugzilla

Comment: @aleroot This bug reported before: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=492371#c17 and only switching to the GTK2 can solve this problem but as I said on my question switching to the GTK2 can cause other Issues.

Comment: It's annoying, but does it really impact your ability to function optimally?

Comment: @LeoWilson IMHO, If it's annoying then it can create less concentration.

Comment: Try to start eclipse with option like "--disable-gpu"

For eclipse it may be '-Dprism.order=j2d' (not tested).


**EDIT**

I had a similar problem with Visual Studio Code. I found the solution: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25934

Comment: @Hermann77 didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 8):

*update 2018/DEC/09*

if you experience a **background flickering** in the eclipse editor on each move of the mouse pointer:

you can tell Eclipe which gtk-version to use:

```
#Gtk3 forced:
export SWT_GTK3=1
eclipse

#Gtk2 forced:
export SWT_GTK3=0
eclipse
```

for Eclipse Oxygen 3 (Version: 4.7.3, March 2018, Build id: 20180308-1800):

put

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

inside your ~/.profile (and restart x-server)

worked for me on Ubuntu 17.10 with Plasma and xorg and xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu: 1.4.0-1

Comment: tell Eclipse which gtk-version to use:


`#Gtk3 forced: export SWT_GTK3=1
eclipse
 
#Gtk2 forced:
export SWT_GTK3=0
eclipse`

Comment: Or just run `SWT_GTK3=0 eclipse`

Answer (score 5):

First check the value of GTK_IM_MODULE in your environment by executing

```
echo $GTK_IM_MODULE
```

In my case the output was “xim”. But Eclipse expect it to be “ibus”. So enter the following command in a terminal session to set it to the value.

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="ibus"
```

use below scripts for run it:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SWT_GTK3=0
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
export GTK_IM_MODULE="ibus"
cd [Eclipse Directory]
./eclipse -showlocation
```

don't forget make it run able:

```
chmod +x eclipse.sh
```

Comment: GTK_IM_MODULE was ibus for me. Still has the problem.

Comment: Worked for me. Also some discussion here: https://subhadipsblog.wordpress.com/2019/01/25/how-to-fix-eclipse-ide-flickering-issue-on-debian/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and here is what worked for me.

Create a bash script file (e.g. `eclipse_gtk2.sh`) containing the following commands.

```
#!/bin/bash
export SWT_GTK3=0
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
cd <path to eclipse directory where the excutable is found>
./eclipse -showlocation
```

Make `eclipse_gtk2.sh` executable

```
chmode +x eclipse_gtk2.sh
```

then simply run the file `./eclipse_gtk2.sh`

Hope it also works for you.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, but I already mentioned on my question that with switching to the GTK2 I have some other issues. I took screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/URIdZ.png

Comment: That is because you are using the dark theme. Unfortunately the Dark theme does not look good with GTK2. Try using the classic or gtk theme instead. Although I prefer the dark theme, I chose to have a better editing performance over a dark interface.

Comment: Voted up for you but I think it's time for me to moving to the non unity desktop. It seems there is no way to make it work properly on GTK3 and unity. I use Eclipse for more than 11 hours a day. to be frank I can not do that with non dark theme.

Comment: In that case you can install Eclipse Color Theme from the Market place and make the code editing area dark. Choose Classic or GTK for the GUI and then choose a different color scheme for the syntax highlight. Not perfect, but somewhere in between.

Comment: Thanks, I made my own dark highlighting but in non dark theme top, bottom, scrolls, tabs, ... will be white and it cause too much distraction.